# Rails/ Device/Mongoid Update email from console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I need to update some email addresses in my production database of some of my old employees. I don't have their account details so I can't update it through the dashboard. Plus I can't delete the account because I need to  keep a track of what they've done in the past.

I tried updating from the console but the value gets set at unconfirmed_email. I haven't received any new confirmation email either.

The same commands works perfectly in development mode. I'm not sure why this is not working. Can't I update the email address through console? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: `User.find(111).confirm!`